# Rebuilding Android LK

Tags: android, bootloader, android-build, fastboot, qualcomm

We are trying to bringup a new MIPI display that we are using for our smart glasses solution. To do this we have roughly followed the guide provided by Qualcomm: https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/db410c/dsi-display-porting-guide-linux-android.pdf

The method of porting a new display required that we modify the Android bootloader (Little Kernel) with the new configuration for the display we are using. This allows us to select the new display using the command:

```
$ fastboot oem select-display-panel <display-name>
```

The problem is that to add this new configuration to LK we need to rebuild the image (emmc_appsboot.mbn). This has been unsuccessful so far.

We found a file within the LK directory that is called `AndroidBoot.mk`. A comment in this file says `“#Android makefile to build lk bootloader as a part of Android Build”`

According to that comment, it seems that LK should be built as a  part of Android build, however we cannot seem to do so. Is this thinking correct?

As per the LK github build instructions, we've also tried running

```
$ make msm8909
```

from the LK directory but we are getting the following error:

```
unrecognised option '-mcpu=cortex-a8'
```

I suspect this may be due to missing part of the toolchain as I've had to manually add `arm-eabi-gcc` to the path variable.

Can anyone provide any information on what command we need to use or what process needs to be followed in order to generate a new LK bootloader file with the updated config?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to an incorrect PATH variable set. I fixed the issue by adding the correct path: ".../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/" to the .bashrc file and re-logging in.